# aws bucket filter download data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am stuck on downloading data from aws s3 bucket, I have the following path:

```
s3://hcp-openaccess/HCP_1200/996782/MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST1_LR/rfMRI_REST1_LR_hp2000_clean.nii.gz
```

And I need this file `rfMRI_REST1_LR_hp2000_clean.nii.gz` for all of 1200 subjects, here in path it is `996782`. So I should iterate with * in `s3://hcp-openaccess/HCP_1200/*/MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST1_LR/rfMRI_REST1_LR_hp2000_clean.nii.gz`

Here is a command I tried to run, with no result:

```
aws s3 sync s3://hcp-openaccess/HCP_1200/ ./Test --include "*_hp2000_clean.nii.gz" --include="*MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST1_LR/" --include="*/"  --exclude="*"
```

It seems Im making mistake `--include` and `--exclude` the filter. How should it be for this query?

Comment: Is the path has multiple files and you want only `.nii.gz` file types, or it has only these file types? And is any thing changes or only the number after `HCP_1200`?

Comment: Try this `aws s3 sync s3://hcp-openaccess/HCP_1200/ ./Test --exclude "*" --include "*/MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST1_LR/rfMRI_REST1_LR_hp2000_clean.nii.gz"`

Comment: @HossamELMansy This directory consists of different file types, not only `nii.gz`. Only the subject number changes after `/HCP_1200/`. It could be 100200, 964938 and os on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
aws s3 sync s3://hcp-openaccess/HCP_1200 ./Test --exclude="*" --include="*MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST1_LR/*"
```

Comment: Should I include `--include="*hp2000_clean.nii.gz"`?

Comment: @PatrickHellman You can put all in one include `--include="*MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST1_LR/*hp2000_clean.nii.gz`.

Comment: Is it ok, that it dangling for several minutes and do nothing after the command? BTW debug shows that it look for matching files in local directory

Comment: @PatrickHellman If the bucket is large, it can hang until all files are identified. The best way is to create your own bucket with few example files in the form you want. Then you can easly test the aws cli commands, before attempting them on large public buckets.